# error: uncaughtException: Unsupported image type in using node.js canvas module

Tags: node.js, canvas

I am using latest version of canvas:

```
   const canvas = require('canvas');
    // req.body.image is coming from canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 

    let image = Buffer.from(
        req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""),
        "base64"
      );
    // result is buffer  <Buffer 75 ab 5a 8a 66 a0 7b fa 67 81 b6 ac 7b ae 22 54 13 91 c3 42 86 82 80 00 00 03 52 52 11 14 80 00 00 b4 00 00 00 8c 02 01 80 00 00 2b c4 d7 07 80 00 00
    console.log('loadImage',image);
    
    const img = await canvas.loadImage(image);
```

However, this throws out an error:

> error: uncaughtException: Unsupported image type

Comment: png vs jpeg 4 more to go...